# How to get the folder path for my case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, substring

I am trying to get the folder path from the src attribute.

```
<img src='project/image/test/grey.png'/>
```

I want to get something like `'project/image/test/'`

Here is my codes but I am not sure what to do next.

```
var folder = $('img').attr('src');
```

Can someone help me out on this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: basic regular expression... or split

Answer (score 1):

Try with [`.lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)

```
var fullpath = $('img').attr('src')
    folder = fullpath.substr(0,fullpath.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regex

```
var src = $('img').attr('src');
var reg = /[^\/]*$/;
var folder = src.replace(reg, ''); // project/image/test/
```

Answer (score 0):

**Split apart, remove last index, join back together**

```
var parts = 'project/image/test/grey.png'.split("/");
parts.pop();
var path = parts.join("/");
var pathWithSlash = parts.join("/") + "/";
```

or

**Match last / and everything after it and remove it**

```
var path = 'project/image/test/grey.png'.replace(/\/[^\/]*$/,"");
var pathWithSlash = 'project/image/test/grey.png'.replace(/[^\/]*$/,"");
```

**Match with regular expression**

```
var path = 'project/image/test/grey.png'.match(/^(.*\/)/)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Hy,

simple and self explaining solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var source = $('img').attr('src');
   var array = source.split('/');
   var output  = "";
    for(var i = 0; i< array.length-1;i++){
        output += array[i]+"/";
    }
    alert(output);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wrgtF/

Answer (score 0):

```
var folderArr =  $('img').attr('src').split('/'),
    folder = '';
folderArr.pop();
folder = folderArr.join('/');
```